# How can I implement UI in Unity using Chromium?

Tags: unity, gui, chrome

I'm looking for an alternative to UI Builder.

Ideally I'd like to have basically a Chromium instance atop Unity3D which would have its JS calls somehow land in the C# (maybe in the "Update" loop it listens to a constant stream of potential calls and the parameters will correspond to function names in my Unity code, I don't know)

here's what I found which doesn't quite live up to my expectations:

- [Unity WebView](https://github.com/gree/unity-webview) doesn't support Windows.
- [3D WebView for Windows and macOS (Web Browser)](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/3d-webview-for-windows-and-macos-web-browser-154144) requires the UI to be served on an actual live URL and for Unity to access it via that URL and for all interaction to be handled via API, impractical or slow at best.
- [PowerUI - HTML/CSS](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/powerui-html-css-10374) is interesting, but was made in 2011. The documentation is all gone. the support for css feature is probably incredibly slim.
- [Embedded Browser](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/embedded-browser-55459) looks pretty good, but I'm unsure that it could be bent into a UI system. I want it to frame my game, not to cover it.
- [Coherent Gameface](https://coherent-labs.com/) looks probably the best,
  although [the CSS implementation seems a tad lackluster](https://coherent-labs.com/Documentation/unity-gameface/df/d2c/css_props.html). Also this project was started in 2012, it's probably carrying very old, very slow code.

[This Unity forum thread may be relevant](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2020-x-removal-of-the-chromium-embedded-framework-and-its-implication-on-asset-store-tools.856417/).
Chromium Embedded Framework was a tool used by some assets on the asset store to create chromium UI but it has been removed.

If not using these assets, how can I implement my idea of using Chromium as my UI layer?

Comment: You want a "web browser control" ... Basically a UI element that acts like a browser. Common in C#/.Net but not common in Unity to my knowledge. Various conotrols will have varying levels of support (which browser back-end, whether they support javascript, etc). There are some on the Unity Asset Store (search "browser")

Comment: I mean yeah I listed https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/embedded-browser-55459 and https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/3d-webview-for-windows-and-macos-web-browser-154144 and https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/powerui-html-css-10374 in my post above and their defects, those are the only three that come up in the asset store.

Comment: @DMGregory what about this : https://zenfulcrum.com/browser/docs/Readme.html?

Comment: It's no Chromium and it's so far only available for editor scripting, but the new [UI Toolkit](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/UIElements.html) is pretty similar to HTML+CSS in philosophy and might become available for ingame UIs in 2021.

Comment: well that's part of the problem I've been having with it ("Ui Toolkit" is one of "Ui Builder's" many names). the blasted thing just won't come out and is in an unusable state. I honeslty don't think it will truly become usable before 2022. personally I've struggled with drawing simple triangles which is something you can do more than easily in pure CSS but in Ui Toolkit you have to have an element and you get an irregular quadrilateral at best. also Blur doesn't exist, drop shadow either.

Comment: Your last two options seem to be viable based on your research so far. How have you tried evaluating them to prove whether your concerns are deal-breakers in practice?

Comment: @DMGregory for Embedded Browsers I haven't bought it yet but I might test it before refunding it if that's an option. As for Coherent Gameface I used their "Get In Touch" button which is the only way to purchase and they mailed me back with some questions about my project and I replied. I'm waiting to hear back. I'm worried they might want some giant sum to use their product like 500€ or more.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the developer of [3D WebView](https://developer.vuplex.com/webview/overview), and I just wanted to clarify that it doesn't have the limitations you thought:

- You can [load local web page assets](https://support.vuplex.com/articles/how-to-load-local-files), not just from a hosted URL.
- 3D WebView's prefabs [automatically detect input through Unity's event system](https://support.vuplex.com/articles/clicking), so most users have no need to call APIs to trigger clicking.
- 3D WebView is also very fast / performant. Many of my customers have told me that they have switched to 3D WebView from other assets for performance reasons.

Comment: Very informative answer. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, @ProllyGeek!